# Asp.net MVC 3 Ajax.beginform submission-what is sent

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a partial view that contains a form that is created using using the ajax.begin form

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "saveStuffHere", null, new AjaxOptions 
   {HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
   OnSuccess = "handleSuccess", OnFailure = "handleError"}))
 {
```

in my controller `saveStuffHere` I have a method `Save`

```
public class saveStuffHereController : Controller
 {
     ....other things...
    /// <summary>
    /// Save the information
    /// </summary>       
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save(I do not know what is passed here)
    {
       .... db code goes here
    }
```

I am saving the form by using the `submit()` method of the form. If I am calling the method in the controller wrong please correct me. But my question is what exactly is being sent back? Or in other words, what should my `Save` method be expecting? 
Basically I do not know what is being passed into my Save method. Is there a way for me to specified what I am passing back? I understand and know how to use jquery ajax, but I would like to try it this way before I move on to jquery ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what exactly is being sent back

Whatever `input` tags you have inside the form.  So if, in the simplest case, you had this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save")) {
    <input type='hidden' value='test' name='AFormField' />
}
```

Then the controller action should expect that one field to be routed through:

```
[Post]
public JsonResult Save(string AFormField)
```

---

If you're using the HTML helpers and a strongly-typed models ...

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save")) {
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model)
}
```

then you can expect the model instance to get routed to the Action:

```
[Post]
public JsonResult Save(MyModelType model)
```

Comment: Dang, I'm ***ed then. My form contains nothing but check boxes created from a jqx widget Grid, and those check boxes are div that has been styles to look like check boxes. The only two input are the email and phone number at the bottom. Well thanks anyways, time to tell the boss I'm not doing it his way and is using jquery ajax instead. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @JackThor You could always use hidden inputs that sync with the checkbox-styled divs.  Really though, I don't think there's much functional difference between JQuery Ajax and Ajax.BeginForm, just different syntax.

Comment: @McGarngle even though the functionality are the same, if I use the `submit()` feature of the form I have no control over what I am sending over correct? Or can I use the onBegin to modify what is being sent? Because not everything needs to be sent over and a jquery ajax will allow me to pick and choose.

Comment: @JackThor `.submit()` is a synchronous postback, and not Ajax ... so I'm not sure why you would use that.  But I see you're right that using `Ajax.BeginForm` doesn't really let you control (directly) what gets sent, whereas with the JQuery `$.post`, you can straightforwardly pass the data to send as an options hash.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again for the help, and love the Simpson pic, I am going home to catch up on the Simpson now :)